# How to get jasmine tests to ignore tabs in multiline string

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function that returns a multiline string like so:

```
example line 1
example line 2
example line 3
```

and I'd like to be able to write like so:

```
it('should get the proper data', () => {
  expect(service.getData('foo').toEqual(
  `example line 1
    example line 2
    example line 3`);
});
```

but of course that will give me this error since the test adds in some whitespace before most lines:

```
Expected 'example line 1
example line 2
example line 3' to equal 'example line 1
    example line 2
    example line 3'.
```

Now I obviously know I could just write my tests slightly differently by adding in `\n` characters, or just manually removing that whitespace, but that looks a bit uglier in my tests.

I'd love it if there were some kind of utility I could use like this:

```
it('should get the proper data', () => {
  expect(service.getData('foo').toEqual(
  util.safeUnindent(`example line 1
    example line 2
    example line 3`));
});
```

Is there some kind of add on I can use that will strip out indentations like this in a safe & reliable way, do I just need to roll my own, or should I just use `\n` characters?

Comment: In this scenario, I use `toContain`. `expect(service.getData('foo')).toContain('example line 1');` (do the same for example line 2 and example line 3). It's good enough for me and I don't necessary worry about the formatting or white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to roll a little of your own (I have not found any out of the box solution).

But a couple of things comes quickly to mind, where the custom matcher is the most elegant, I find.

1. Using `toContain` to check that expected content is in the returned string
2. Using `toMatch` - to check using regular expresion (RegEx)
3. Using custom matchers - very reusable and easy to read

See https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/matchers, https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/custom_matcher and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions

Function to test:

```
function getData(x){
    return `
    example line 1
    example line 2
    example line 3
    `
}
```

Test setup:

```
function trimmedLines(untrimmed){
    // trim leading and trailing spaces and newlines and split at inner newlines
    const lines = untrimmed.trim().replace(/^\n+/, '').replace(/\n+$/, '').split('\n')
    const trimmedLines = []
    lines.forEach(line => {
        // trim and add each line to new array
        trimmedLines.push(line.trim())
    });
    // return a trimmed string
    return trimmedLines.join('\n')
}

const customMatchers = {
    ToEqualTrimmed: function(matchersUtil) {
        return {
            compare: function(actual, expected) {
                if (expected === undefined) expected = '';
                const result = { };
                result.pass = matchersUtil.equals(
                    trimmedLines(actual),
                    trimmedLines(expected)
                )

                if (result.pass) {
                    result.message = "Expected " + actual + " to be trimmed equal to" + expected;
                } else {
                    result.message = "Expected " + actual + " to be trimmed equal to" + expected + ' But was not!';
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
};

beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers(customMatchers);
});

describe("Outer test desc", () => {
    it('should get the proper data', () => {
        const output = getData('foo')
        // this fails
        expect(output).toEqual(
          `example line 1
            example line 2
            example line 3`);
        // these 3 pass
        expect(output).toContain('example line 1')
        expect(output).toContain('example line 2')
        expect(output).toContain('example line 3')
        // this passes too
        expect(output).toMatch('[ \n]*example line 1[ \n]*example line 2[ \n]*example line 3[ \n]*');
        // passes too
        expect(output).ToEqualTrimmed(
          `example line 1
            example line 2
            example line 3`);


    });

});
```

The `[ \n]*` matches zero or more spaces or newlines.

Comment: Very cool, I was not aware you could make custom matchers, I've been away from Jasmine for a few years.  Please see the answer I submitted to my own question below, do you think that will work or would it be better practice to use something more like this?

Comment: Personally I would use the custom matcher - It gives a cleaner look and better readability. But whether you use your `dedent` or my `trimmedLines` is up to you. As long as it gets the job done. in `trimmedLines`I have removed empty lines at start and end of text, but its use depends on what is actually inputted.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking back to an old project I contributed to, TSLint. I recalled their tests had a `dedent` method for testing strings of TypeScript code as input/output into their linter.  I found [their `dedent` method source](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/285fc1db18d1fd24680d6a2282c6445abf1566ee/src/utils.ts#L72C53-L89), and here is [an example usage with a string of JSON code it is used on](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/285fc1db18d1fd24680d6a2282c6445abf1566ee/src/formatters/jsonFormatter.ts#L28-L50)

So I modified this a bit, simplified it really, into this which seems to work for me.

```
export function dedent(inputStrings: TemplateStringsArray, ...values: any[]) {
  //Convert template string arr into a real string
  const fullString = inputStrings.reduce(
    (accumulator, str, i) => `${accumulator}${values[i - 1]}${str}`
  );

  //on each line, remove any leading whitespace
  return fullString
    .split('\n')
    .map((line) => line.replace(/^[\t\s]*/, ''))
    .join('\n');
}
```

Which I can use like this, which is cool because it works like a function but I don't need the opening or closing parenthesis

```
import { dedent } from 'test-utils';

it('should get the proper data', () => {
  expect(service.getData('foo'))
    .toEqual(dedent`example line 1
                    example line 2
                    example line 3`);
});
```

Right now in the early stages of my project this seems to work well for my existing tests.  Does this seem like a good way to move forward with this, or am I missing something that might bite me in the future?